# Redirect|Forward from old URL to new URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect, url-routing

I had a route and a method that manipulated URLs in this way:

```
http://domain.com/combivent?email=WGA1cUtKZi4
```

Now that URL has changed into this one:

```
http://domain.com/?email=WGA1cUtKZi4
```

But old emails still keep the old one. I need to redirect each URL from the old way to the new one. For example if I call this `http://domain.com/combivent?email=WGA1cUtKZi4` then I should redirect to `http://domain.com/?email=WGA1cUtKZi4`how I can achieve this in Symfony2? Can I use any kind of wildcard in routes or do I need to keep both methods and handle this internally? Can this be done at `.htaccess` level? Any advice?

This is how the `.htaccess` looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Remove combivent word from the URL when call a brand page
    RewriteRule ^combivent?email=([^/]+)$  /?email=$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]    
</IfModule>
```

Furthermore this `domain.com` is a Alias of a VirtualHost that share three domains. Think in the VH definition as:

```
ServerName maindomain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
ServerAlias domain1.com
```

**Update**

Below is the full `.htaccess` definition:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Remove combivent word from the URL when call a brand page
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=[^&]+ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^combivent/?$ / [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than digging into the `.htaccess` you could just redirect the old route to the new route in your routing.

```
new_route:
    path: /
    defaults: ...

old_route:
    path: /combivent
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: new_route
        permanent: true
```

As you are using annotations you would just need to either name your new route or find out the generated name and use that in your "old_route" definition.

*Updated with your actual setup*

<kbd>PDOneBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml</kbd>

```
pdone:
    resource: "@PDOneBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

# add this
combivent:
    path: /combivent
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: brand
        permanent: true
```

<kbd>PDOneBundle\Controller\BrandPageController</kbd>

```
class BrandPageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return array
     * @Route("/combivent", name="combivent") <!-- remove this
     * @Route("/", name="brand")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Annotations for routing, can be achieved the same? How?

Comment: You could just put it in your `app/config/routing.yml` where, I assume, you have added your base annotations "import". Alternatively you could put it in a special  `redirect.yml` file that you can then link to from your `routing.yml` as a resource.

Comment: I would advise using @Qoop's suggestion. If you use Symfony's framework to do this you won't have to worry if in future the site moves from apache to nginx or another http server.

Comment: @Qoop [this](https://gist.github.com/paquitodev/dab1eab81e77ef0cb044) is my current project setup, could you edit your answer based on this sources? I'm still no so good with routing and I'm not following you at all

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following rule to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^combivent?email=([^/]+)$  /?email=$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

**Edit:** You need to add it **above** the following line:

```
# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

Comment: Isn't working. I have added to `/web/.htaccess` file in a Symfony 2.7 project

Comment: Sorry, it's late here. I have just updated the answer.

Comment: Check the main post I've added `.htaccess` info. That way isn't working either, perhaps I am writing this at the wrong place on the whole `mod_rewrite` definition

Comment: @ReynierPM Yes, you need to add it before the rule above it. `RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]` is preventing any further rewrites because it satisfies every pattern, and has the `L` flag.

Comment: Do I need to restart Apache service or something else? How I make sure the rule is being called? Still not working

Answer (score 1):

This rule is problematic:

```
# Remove combivent word from the URL when call a brand page
RewriteRule ^combivent?email=([^/]+)$  /?email=$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

as you cannot match `QUERY_STRING` using `RewriteRule`. Use a `RewriteCond` instead:

```
# Remove combivent word from the URL when call a brand page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)combivent/?$ / [L,R=301]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be carrier over to nee target automatically.

**Full .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Remove combivent word from the URL when call a brand page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)combivent/?$ / [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: You mean this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=[^&]+ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^combivent/?$ / [L,R=301]` or this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=[^&]+ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^combivent/?$ / [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]` neither is working for me

Comment: No, is not working. You can check it [here](http://share.qa.pdone.com/app_dev.php/combivent?email=6ozk_zxZu-A). I have tested in a new Firefox with cache clear and also in Chrome incognito window, none works

Comment: Since this is a Symfony2 project then we will have `http://domain.com/combivent?email=WGA1cUtKZi4` for prod env and `http://domain.com/app_dev.php/combivent?email=6ozk_zxZu-A` for dev env (share.qa.pdone.com is the real domain). The `.htaccess` is at `/web` folder on the root path of the project. `app.php` is the script that handle everything, take a look to the edited post

Comment: Is not working yet it redirects to `http://share.qa.pdone.com/var/www/html/mt020415-00-pdonereptool/web/?email=6ozk_zxZu-A` should be `http://share.qa.pdone.com/?email=6ozk_zxZu-A`